# Trying to use bs4 to skip an attribute if there is no data

Tags: python, import, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a program that will pull data from a URL and format it so that I can copy into another program. I've got everything working except I can't get it to skip an item if there is no img src in the imagelink tag.

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
res = requests.get('http://hzws.selco.info/prototype.php?type=new-arrivals&lib=nor&collect=Bnewnf,Bnewmys,Bnewf,Bnewsf&days=14&key=7a8adfa9aydfa999997af')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

img = soup.select('imagelink') #why won't this pull anything?!?!?!?!
link = soup.select('cataloglink')

length = min([14, len(img)])
for i in range(length):
  img1 = img[i].getText()
  link1 = link[i].getText()
  print('<div>' + link1 + img1 + '</a></div>')
```

Right now this prints all of the URLs regardless of whether or not there is an imagelink attached to it. I've tried numerous different things to get it to skip an item if there is no img src. Any ideas?

Comment: I opened that url in a browser and there is no tag named `'imagelink'`. Is your goal to get all of the "img src" links, i.e. `'img src="http://..'`?

Comment: Is `imagelink` a `class`? Why not try using `img = soup.find('img', {'class':'imagelink`})` then?

Comment: Sorry! I should have specified. imagelink is in the xml in the page source. Running that inside of select is the only way I can get it to print anything. Trying to get the img src links that are tied to the urls.

 And soup.find returned an error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [BS4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), It looks like "lxml" is actually a HTML parser. You should replace it with "lxml-xml", since you're trying to scrape an XML page. That should be working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I replaced it and then ran it, but now nothing prints at all. The program just runs and then nothing...

Comment: Note that XML is case-sensitive. `imagelink` won't be recognized, `ImageLink` will. Same applies for `cataloglink`. You should change it to `CatalogLink`.

Comment: Oh! Excellent! That got it printing everything. Any ideas on how to get it to only print the `<Items>` that have both an `img src` and `CatalogLink` in it?

Comment: You need to check if `img1` and `link1` are not empty strings, just before your print statement. That should skip the possible empty `ImageLink` and `CatalogLink` brackets.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'm trying this, but to no avail, however.
    length = min([14, len(img)])
    for i in range(length):
        img1 = img[i].getText()
        link1 = link[i].getText()
    
        if img1 or link1 == '':
            next(length)
       else:
            print('<div>' + link1 + img1 + '</a></div>')   
_sorry, i'm new and am not quite sure how to format this in a comment_

Comment: I don't know what's making you stuck, it's a simple if statement
`if img1 != "" and link1 != "": print('<div>' + link1 + img1 + '</a></div>')`
unless I didn't understand your question?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still pretty new to python and was trying to overthink it. You rock. That solved it!